# Scrollview inside linear layout not scrolling

Tags: android, scrollview

I'm trying to make a day view similar to Google Calendar but I can't seem to get my scrollview to scroll. My scrollview is located inside a linear layout. I also have a button that needs to be below the scrollview. As a note both the button and the scrollview have a layout_weight associated with them.

Here are the relevant snippets:

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0px" 
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <include android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/calendar_day_view" />

</ScrollView>
```

calendar_day_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/eightAM" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nineAM"
            android:translationY="60dp" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tenAM"
            android:translationY="120dp" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/elevenAM"
            android:translationY="180dp" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/twelvePM"
            android:translationY="240dp" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/onePM"
            android:translationY="300dp" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/twoPM"
            android:translationY="360dp" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/threePM"
            android:translationY="420dp" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fourPM"
            android:translationY="480dp" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fivePM"
            android:translationY="540dp" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sixPM"
            android:translationY="600dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <include android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        layout="@layout/calendar_horizontal_delims" />"

</LinearLayout>
```

and calendar_horizontal_delims.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View android:translationY="60dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:translationY="120dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:translationY="180dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:translationY="240dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:translationY="300dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:translationY="360dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:translationY="420dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:translationY="480dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:translationY="540dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:translationY="600dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#000000"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/calendar_day_view" />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I don't want a horizontal scrollview.

Comment: Then use ScrollView instead of HorizontalScrollView , it will solve your problem

Comment: That reduces my calendar to only the 8 AM slot and it hides the button that I want to be at the bottom of my layout. And for some reason I still can't scroll.

Comment: If you have a button below to the ScrollView then you should not use match_parent for height in ScrollView. You need to fix your scrollview hight as (screen height - button height). for eg your screen height is 1024 and you have a button with 100 dp then you should set the scrollview height as 924dp. I thing it will resolve your problem.

Comment: My problem is not in displaying. My problem is that the scrollview refuses to scroll even if there is more stuff to display after the cut off point in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the use of the `ScrollView`:

**`ScrollView only supports vertical scrolling. For horizontal scrolling, use HorizontalScrollView.`**

More info:

**[ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)**